# Protractor Cucumber - 'Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, protractor, cucumber

Step definitions files are not picking up while executing the below error message is displayed.

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /Users/Scope/node_modules/cucumber/src/cli/configuration_builder.js:137:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ConfigurationBuilder.<anonymous> (/Users/Scope/node_modules/cucumber/src/cli/configuration_builder.js:134:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.tryCatcher (/Users/Scope/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at PromiseSpawn._promiseFulfilled (/Users/Scope/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/generators.js:97:49)
    at ConfigurationBuilder.<anonymous> (/Users/Scope/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/generators.js:201:15)
    at ConfigurationBuilder.expandSupportCodePaths (/Users/Scope/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cli/configuration_builder.js:225:22)
    at ConfigurationBuilder.<anonymous> (/Users/Scope/node_modules/cucumber/src/cli/configuration_builder.js:36:37)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.tryCatcher (/Users/Scope/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at PromiseSpawn._promiseFulfilled (/Users/Scope/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/generators.js:97:49)
```

protractor.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'https://www.google.com',

  capabilities: {
    browserName:'chrome'
  },

  framework: 'custom',

  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  // frameworkPath: require.resolve('serenity-js'),

  specs: [
    './e2e/features/*.feature'
  ],

  cucumberOpts: {

    compiler: 'ts:ts-node/register',
    require: [
      "./e2e/features/step_definitions/*_step.ts",
      // path.resolve(process.cwd(), './e2e/step_definitions/Test_step.ts')
    ],
    tags: '@Test',
    strict: false,
    format: ["pretty", "json:report/json/cucumber_report.json"],
    dryRun: false,
  },

  onPrepare: function () {
    project: "./e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json";
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }
};
```

I've tried the suggestion in stackoverflow but it didn't worked for me.

- Cucumber version: 3.0.6
- Node version: 8.2.1
- Protractor version: 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

ts-node would need to be installed as cucumber is `require`ing that.

`npm install ts-node`